# ExitHandler in Eclipse RCP is not invoked when closing window

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP Application (Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)). I have an exit-command specifiied in my application.xmi. To this command I have suited handler:

```
<handlers xmi:id="_6wlLfcgZEeSyMNYR5xypkQ"
elementId="test.handler.quitCommand"
contributionURI="bundleclass://Test/test.handlers.QuitHandler" 
command="_6wlLfMgZEeSyMNYR5xypkQ"
/>
```

The handler is invoked when I use the corespondent menu item (Exit).

Now when I use ALT + F4 or close the application window via the X this handler is omitted and the application just closes.

I would like to invoke the `ExitHandler` when i click on the X. How can I achieve this in RCP 4?

Comment: Do you use the compatibility layer or is this a pure e4 application?

Comment: I would prefer a pure e4 solution.

Comment: OK, then you'd probably have to go with Greg's answer. Otherwise you could register an `IWorkbenchListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the handler is difficult, but the `@PreSave` method in your life cycle class is always called during the application shutdown.

```
@PreSave
public void preSave()
{
   ...
}
```